# Localization for multiple languages at same time

Tags: c#, localization

I have a console MEF application which convert files. There are some classes for logging warnings and errors, each in separate assembly. Every message, which I want to log, goes to LoggerProxy class and from it to all relevant loggers. I'm using strongly typed resource names, e.g. Message.NoFilesFound. Here is my problem - the strings for me must be in english or german, but messages for file owner must go in his language. It means that Message.NoFilesFound should be in german on console and in the log file, but e.g. italian in the mail for customer.

How can I setup the system for thist task?

Now I have:

```
class Main()
{
    Message.Culture = new CultureInfo("it");
    LoggerProxy.Write( Destination.Console|Destination.Customer, Message.NoFilesFound );
}

class LoggerProxy
{

    [ImportMany]
    Lazy<ILogger,ILoggerMetadata>[] Loggers { get; set; }

    public void Write( Destination dest, string msg )
    {
        foreach ( var logger in Loggers )
            if ( (logger.Metadata.Destination & dest ) != 0 )
                logger.Value.Write( msg );
    }
}
```

I would like to have the culture change in LoggerProxy.Write, but the parameter is already localized string.

Comment: if the parameter is already localized, then I don't know what you expect. You can pray for a function 'relocalize' to come along, but see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy. Do tell us what it is _exactly_ that you expect/require

Comment: balexandre: console MEF application

Comment: sehe: I would like to say Log( Message.FileNotFound ) and have one line on console "Datei nicht gefunden", same line in logfile, but in the mail for our customer in Italy "File non trovato". We cannot read logfiles in italian, and not all customers can read messages in german/english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to say Log( Message.FileNotFound ) and have one line on console "Datei nicht gefunden", same line in logfile, but in the mail for our customer in Italy "File non trovato". We cannot read logfiles in italian, and not all customers can read messages in german/english. – Gabriel Gnatowski 2 mins ago

You need to refactor the interfaces so that the Write method shown get's the unlocalized message id (Message.NoFilesFound).

Then there are two approaches. Either the Logger (logger) has a member that portrays the locale ID to be used by the logger, or will be able to autonomically translate the ID to a message (perhaps, no translation at all, when logging to a database, so you can view the log in your preferred language at a later time, or simply for compression purposes).

I'm nog aware of any interpolation strings, but suspect you have them ("Fichier {0} non trouvé", e.g.) so you'd need to be able to pass these as well. A `params string[]` is neat on the calling site (LoggerProxy.Write) but down the chain IEnumerable would be most versatile.

I suppose all of this is rather superficial, but I think it answers the question at least as far as I got the question clear.

Comment: This is of course the simplest solution (which we use for old Delphi application), but I was hoping to find something integrated in .NET. With this solution I can forget the automatically generating strongly typed resources from resx file.

Comment: If you can explain why you think that is _a given_ perhaps we can find _the real question_

Comment: I'found a solution with resx: I generate resx for invariant culture with values equal property names, e.g. for Message.NoFilesFound stands string "NoFilesFound". The LoggerProxy gets then from ResourceManager the correct localized message for every logger. So I have strongly typed messages and can change them for every output.

Comment: Well that's an awesome answer, Gabriel. BUT: wouldn't you automatically loose the info that would have been interpolated (with {0} and {1} e.g.) ??!
I think it should be OK for you to answer that, and accept it because it is REALLY a useful gem that is overlooked by many (apparently)!